# Disable a button using Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have a form built via Razor Pages. The form consists of two submit buttons - each of them is assigned to an appropriate `asp-page-handler`, like this:

```
@page "{id:int}"
//...
<form asp-action="Post">
    <input type="submit" asp-page-handler="Approve" class="btn btn-success" value="Approve" />
    <input type="submit" asp-page-handler="Decline" class="btn btn-danger" value="Decline" />
</form>
```

My handlers work correctly. Now I need to disable the Approve button by some condition. Unfortunately I can't figure out what is the right way to achieve this using Razor Pages?

I tried the following (condition is simplified):

```
@{ var disableTag = "disabled"; } 
...
<input type="submit" asp-page-handler="Approve" class="btn btn-success" value="Approve"  @disableTag />
```

After launch of the app, the markup remained unchanged and the button is still enabled. Seems like the `asp-page-handler` tag forces the Razor engine to ignore `@disableTag` variable.

Next attempt was (`@disableTag` was put in front of `asp-page-handler`):

```
<input type="submit" @disableTag asp-page-handler="Approve" class="btn btn-success" value="Approve" /
```

Now the page rendered correctly (`disabled` tag is there), but the handler itself stopped working (the markup shows `asp-page-handler="Approve"` as a plain tag instead of something like `/{PageName}/{id}?handler=Approve`)

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Conditions can be used in your `cshtml` file in the following manner.
`<form asp-action="Post">
    @if(some condition){
<input type="submit" asp-page-handler="Approve" class="btn btn-success" value="Approve"  disabled/>
}
@else{
    <input type="submit" asp-page-handler="Decline" class="btn btn-danger" value="Decline" />
}
</form>`
I hope it answers your question

Comment: thanks, that should work in the most simple situation. But it doesn't seem it is an elegant one

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to think the tag helper way. Disable is a property that you can define like all the other properties which are supported by the equivalent tag helper. Below you can find two different ways do define your disable attribute for your buttons:

```
@{
    bool disable1 = true;
    string disable2 = "disable";    // or string disable2 = null;
}

<h2>Test</h2>
<form asp-action="Post">
    <input type="submit" asp-page-handler="Approve" class="btn btn-success" value="Approve" disabled="@(disable1 ? "disabled" : null)" />
    <input type="submit" asp-page-handler="Decline" class="btn btn-danger" value="Decline" disabled="@disable2" />
</form>
```

I hope it helps.

**Complete Example**

*DisabledButton.cshtml.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace MyWebApplication.Pages
{
    public class DisabledButtonModel : PageModel
    {
        public bool Disbale1 { get; set; }
        public bool Disbale2 { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }

        public ActionResult OnPostApprove()
        {
            Disbale1 = true;
            Disbale2 = false;

            return Page();
        }

        public ActionResult OnPostDecline()
        {
            Disbale1 = false;
            Disbale2 = true;

            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

*DisabledButton.cshtml*

```
@page "{handler?}"
@model MyWebApplication.Pages.DisabledButtonModel

<form asp-action="Post">
    <input type="submit" asp-page-handler="Approve" class="btn btn-success" value="Approve" disabled="@(Model.Disbale1 ? "disabled" : null)" />
    <input type="submit" asp-page-handler="Decline" class="btn btn-danger" value="Decline" disabled="@(Model.Disbale2 ? "disabled" : null)" />
</form>
```

Comment: to clarify: I does work if there is NO asp-page-handler attribute in front, which is the case here

Comment: I added a complete example. It works because I tested it.

Comment: thank you, that solves the question. However I'm still unclear why tag-helper brokes  the inline statemement like this @(Model.ApproveAllowed ? "disabled" : null). Hopefully will get the answer from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring#avoiding-tag-helper-conflicts